# How to add a non editable field using install4j - value of this is not static and should be displayed from a user defined variable

Tags: install4j

I would like to be able to add a key/value pair label in an install screen. The key is a static text. The value is a dynamic value and a value from a variable should be used to display the value label. I'm not able to do so using install4J. I see options like a textArea, textfield that will enable to be able to do so. However, these are editable fields and does not serve my purpose. I want a non editable field to display a value from a variable. This is not a system variable. This should be a user defined variable. I'm using install4j 4.2 version. Any help in this area is highly appreciated.

---

Thanks for the response. I was able to create key/value pair. However, I'm not able to define my own installer variable. Can you please let me know where I can define an installer variable that can be used in the key/value pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "Key value pair" form component that does exactly what you need. It is available in install4j 4.2.

In the "Value label/Text" property, you can use an installer variable like

```
${installer:myValue}
```

for displaying dynamic text.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to create key/value pair. However, I'm not able to define my own installer variable. Can you please let me know where I can define an installer variable that can be used in the key/value pair?

Comment: You can use a "Set a variable" action or call `context.setVariable(...)` in any script.